# Why wasn't Peter grandma's favourite?

Tags: plot-explanation, hereditary

Since grandma wanted to get in Peter (posess his body after she died), why was his sister her favourite (as stated by her mother) and not him? Why weren't they closer (like for example his sister was with grandma)?

Comment: @ToddWilcox from what I understand,  grandma was a demon and after she died the demon wanted another body (a male one this time). That's what I am trying to say

Comment: Makes sense, now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on how I understood the movie, Peter's grandma was part of the cult, while ever since Annie allowed Charlie near her, Charlie was possessed by Paiman. Grandma worshipped Paiman, Paiman is in Charlie, so it follows that Charlie was grandma's favorite.

That said, as Charlie mentions in the movie, her grandma would have preferred she was a boy, as it would be more fitting for the demon she's hosting. That's why the events of the movie transpire—it's just a plot to get Paiman into a male host.

Comment: Yes I guess that's right. I wasn't really sure about the role of Charlie in the movie since it leaves certain things blurry but I can now see that Charlie was possessed all the time but the demon in her was not in 'full mode' since he wanted a male body